# How do I get ruby debugger to work in sinatra with shotgun?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-debug, shotgun

Is there a way of running shotgun to allow for ruby debugger statements to run? the `-d` flag seems to be just for debugging output.

Answer (score 3):

In order to find the best way to debug sinatra app, I created a repo at github. The most useful part is step into method debug, which looks like below.

[image]

Here is the repo: https://github.com/hlee/sinatra_debugger_example

I also confirmed this example support shotgun as well. try as below

```
cd sinatra_debugger_example
bundle
shotgun config.ru
```

and visit: `http://localhost:9393`, you will be able to use pry debug and stepping.

About debugger & pry:

1. the example project support both debugger and pry.
2. I personally perfer pry better.

I hope it helps you.